# Is there some way though PHP which will display a picture detail on click out of list of a pictures?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, loops, web

I'm doing a PHP assignment having a very basic knowledge of PHP.
I'm looping through a list of pictures from S3, but after looping through I want a selected picture to be opened on click. I'm clueless on how it will proceed further.

I have a product.php page which has to redirect to single .php.

Comment: Do you want to handle click?

Comment: Yes I do want to

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: I tried but since i'm new so I could not find a way.Anyways it's done now. Thank you for consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is server side language that send html tags to render in browser side, so you can use client side languages (exp: javascript) to handle it.

Comment: You means forums? can you plz give some further hint? I don't need code

Comment: edit the question - do not add code as comments please as it is very hard to read

Comment: @raminashrafimanesh sir your hint worked and I made it through some simple js techniques

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HTML: [Anchors aka Links](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp):

```
$images = [
    'a.jpg',
    'b.jpg'
];

echo '<ul>';
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="single.php?image=' . $image . '">';

    // small preview-images could be prefixed with 'thumb_' . $image
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width='100'/>';

    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

In `single.php` you will get the clicked Image with `$_GET['image']`

Comment: I knew it but it was not sufficient . I did not suppose to open image only but its relevant information from the data base as well. Anyways thank you

Comment: Well then display the [exif-data](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exif-read-data.php) in `single.php`